# table layout size

Tags: android

I must need to use table layout. but i want table layout with fixed size when there is no record or two row. after deleted that two records(row) size is fixed.
and when more than two records(row) are added then size of table is increasing. table layout created on runtime. is it possible ? how? 
i create table layout at runtime and add row dynamically its working and also size is also increasing but when i put fixed size then the size is not increasing.
Suggest me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you  can set the fixed size by design time in xml or programmatically set in code and check whether the rows>2 the change to wrap_content other set as fixed size

Comment: yes, i do that but error is occur.
This is my code:
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);
TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
     TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
     TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
table.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: try this table.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Comment: it is not working. My layout is: <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
       android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="130dip">
      </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>                       and it shows first time correctly but when i click button to add rows then error occur